# monotonicity of sample averages tails as a function of sample size

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Let $X_1,...$ be iid mean zero random variables. The LLN says $\overline{X}_n\to 0$. I am curious if the following is true: is $P(|\overline{X}_n|>x)>P(|\overline{X}_{n+1}|>x)$ for $x$ arbitrary; is $|\overline{X}_{n+1}|$ stochastically less than $|\overline{X}_{n}|$? By the LLN the limsup as $n\to\infty$ is $0$ but maybe there is fluctuation and the sequence isn't monotone decreasing.  I could not even establish the case $n=1$ and I think I found playing around in R a counterexample. But I don't understand how it could be that averaging could increase the tail probability, and would be interested in knowing if anything can be said, eg, maybe $P(|\overline{X}_n|>x)>P(|\overline{X}_{n+k}|>x)$ for some (distribution-dependent) $k$ or certain values $x$.

Full disclosure: I posted this on math se a couple days ago and it got closed for not having enough background. I don't know what to add and thought maybe the intrinsic value maybe would be appreciated here. It isn't homework. I think it is a basic part of understanding concentration to the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Let $X_i$ be $-p$ with probability $1-p$ and $1-p$ with probability $p$ (ie, a recentered Bernoulli) and let $p$ be small.

- $|\bar X_1|$ is $p$ with probability $1-p$ and larger than, say, 1/4, with probability $p$
- $|\bar X_2|$ is $p$ with probability $1-2p$ and larger than 1/4 with probability $2p$

Comment: I think it *is* true for large enough $x$

Comment: About an hour playing around in R suggests that it is true for large enough $x$ but my intuitions here are all weak especially after your counterexample. Also if there were such a critical value $x$ I thought I would have found something googling around.